# File types from rpm package file

Tags: linux, rpm

Is there any way to get file types (or more exactly, list of binaries) from rpm package file without unpacking it? It's assumed that there is a rpm file which isn't installed and we need just to learn file types inside it.

EDIT: I don't need just list of files, but files' types.

Answer (score 3):

For a single package `rpm -qpl package.rpm` works.

If you want to select multiple packages and get file lists for all of them at once (with an indication of what package they are from) then `--filesbypkg` is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `-filesbypkg` switch (see the [man page](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html)):

```
rpm -q -filesbypkg -p file.rpm
```

From the man page:

```
 --filesbypkg<br>
    This lists all the files in each package.
```

If you want to filter that down to specific types, that would be easy with some shell stuff.